# jQuery load() causing a jQuery plugin error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following page:

```
<body>
  <div id="menuBar"> </div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="700" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</body>

<script src="../Scripts/jQuery.mazeBoard.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
     var mazeArray = ...
     $("#menuBar").load("/Views/UpperMenu.html");
     $("#myCanvas").mazeBoard(mazeArray);
  })
</script>
```

mazeBoard is a jQuery plugin defined in mazeBoard.js:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.mazeBoard = function (mazeData) {

        this.element = $(this)[0];
        var context = this.element.getContext("2d");

        draw on canvas...

        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Strangely, unless I delete the row `$("#menuBar").load("/Views/UpperMenu.html")` I get a "mazeboard is not a function" error. This error disappears when the row is deleted.

Comment: unable to replicate, https://jsfiddle.net/v6exkas9/

Comment: Try to change jquery library another version.. it solves your problem..

Comment: I get the same error. jonLuci, I get the error only when that line is not commented.

Comment: Simplest thing to try is to swap the order of the two lines; `.mazeBoard()` first, then `.load()`.

Comment: can you show us the contents of `Views/UpperMenu.html` ? you may have `<script>` tags which interfere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say why this error might occur but probably to do with `.load()` being asynchronous.

Simplest thing to try is to swap the order of the two lines :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mazeArray = ...
    $("#myCanvas").mazeBoard(mazeArray);
    $("#menuBar").load("/Views/UpperMenu.html");
});
```

If that doesn't work, then you can await completion of `.load()` before initializing `.mazeBoard()` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mazeArray = ...;
    $("#menuBar").load("/Views/UpperMenu.html", function() {
        $("#myCanvas").mazeBoard(mazeArray);
    });
});
```